# Program can't find xml data in file

Tags: python, xml

My code (Python3) is supposed to print COLOR:Red│. When I run it, it doesn't give me an error message, it doesnt print anything. Here is my code and below is the xml file where the data is located:

```
import os, csv
from xml.etree import ElementTree

file_name = 'data.xml'
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('xml', file_name))
dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)

attri = dom.findall('attribute')
lst = []

for c in attri:
    name = c.find('name').text
    value = c.find('value').text
    lst = (name + ':' + value)
    print(lst, end = "│") 



<?xml version="1.0"?>
<all>
<items>
<item>
<attributes>
<attribute>
<name>COLOR</name>
<value>Red</value>
</attributes>
</attribute>
</item>
</items>
</all>
```

Comment: ups, i see. this is not my code. in the original file it was </attributes> correctly

Comment: Provided that the XML is fixed, you'll need to first get the `all` tag, then `items` in it, then `item` in it, then `attributes` in it, then finally find all `attribute` tags in it in order to print name/value of each. `findall()` searches only the immediate children of the currently selected node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attri = dom.findall('attribute')` is returning no results.

The section of the docs titled [Finding interesting elements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) notes that

> `Element.findall()` finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element.

But that

> More sophisticated specification of which elements to look for is possible by using [XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath).

The simplest fix would be to change your code to

```
for c in dom.findall('.//attribute'):
    name = c.find('.//name').text
    value = c.find('.//value').text
    print(name + ':' + value, end="│")
```

See [Supported XPath syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) for more information.